# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist in ie browser

Tags: java, selenium

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver
>   executable does not exist:
>   C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\ttt\‪C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\ttt\IEDriverServer.exe
>     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:137)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:132)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$000(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:35)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:188)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:346)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:281)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:211)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:150)
>     at t.test.main(test.java:16)

```
public class test {

static WebDriver d;

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","‪C:\\Users\\Administrator\\eclipse-workspace\\ttt\\IEDriverServer.exe");


    d=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    d.get("https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6511");

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to give System.setProperty as;

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","IEDriverServer.exe");
```

Comment: above mentioned code not working for me